# Corona related documents with Ryanair

Tags: covid-19, ryanair

I'm flying Ryanair from Germany to Bulgaria and got an email with the following text:

> As governments continue to introduce Covid-19 rules and restrictions, it’s very important that you check the most up to date travel guidelines with the relevant local authorities before your trip.
> You must ensure you complete any additional travel documentation that is required, for every country that you fly to and bring it with you on your trip.
> Failure to present this mandatory documentation will result in your travel/entry being denied by local authorities and in some cases, may result in a fine by local authorities of up to 500.00 EUR.

When I go to the website of the German Foreign ministry I can find the following text:

> Seit dem 1. Juni 2020 ist deutschen Staatsangehörigen die Einreise aus Deutschland und anderen EU-Staaten nach Bulgarien ohne verpflichtende häusliche Quarantäne wieder gestattet. Bei der Einreise ist ein Einreiseformular mit Kontaktdaten auszufüllen, das am Flughafen/Grenzstellen erhältlich ist.

The German foreign ministry says that the Bulgarian corona document is available at the airport/border crossing point, however the email from Ryanair makes it sound like I need to print it and bring it with me. Can Ryanair refuse to let me on the plane without a printed document? Do I need to have it with me or is filling it at the destination airport enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one asked for the document either when boarding the plane or when clearing immigration in Bulgaria. I would still recommend people to print the documents just in case, but it seems like in practice they are not always required.